# Hidde element in collapse menu bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im working with a navbar from bootstrap and dropdown but actually Im implemented an arrow image when the user clicks over the first element, I use css to put the image but if I collapse the navbar even when I push the dropdown the arrow appears.

What do you recommend me to hide the arrow in mobiles?

My code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

My Css:

```
a[aria-expanded="true"]{
background-image: url("http://www.russianmachineneverbreaks.com/wp-content/themes/nebula/images/arrow_up_24x24.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: bottom;
}
```

The fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dxnemmrd/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
a[aria-expanded="true"]::after{
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  height: 17px;
  width: 30px;
  float: right;
  margin-left:5px;
    background-image: url("http://www.russianmachineneverbreaks.com/wp-content/themes/nebula/images/arrow_up_24x24.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: bottom;
}
@media (max-width:768px){
  a[aria-expanded="true"]::after{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

[jsfiddle.net/dxnemmrd/4/](https://jsfiddle.net/dxnemmrd/4/)

Comment: Thank you, is just like I need!!

Comment: it's better to use ::after and ::before for the icons than use the background, you will have more flexibility

Comment: I check in my debug mode but the image is in the rigth side of the text and I need it down of the text, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one also

[BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/YBuGzS6eHi#)

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  a[aria-expanded="true"]{
background-image: url("http://www.russianmachineneverbreaks.com/wp-content/themes/nebula/images/arrow_up_24x24.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: bottom;
}
}
```